# Elegant way to calculate probability of a randomly selected person from a test group being sick, given specificity, sensitivity, and test results

Tags: probability, intuition, conditional-probability

Given a decease and a test that identifies:

- 99.9% of sick patients as sick (sensitivity)
- 99.8% of healthy patients as healthy (specificity)

15 of 5000 patients were tested positive, what is the probability that a randomly selected patient from that group is sick?

I have solved this issue naively by just using the definition of sensitivity and specificity, but is there a more elegant or efficient way to solve this problem?

## Naive approach

That probability is $P(sick) = \frac{tp+fn}{5000}$, so we need to find the true positives and the false negatives. We can solve the following four equations for the unknown four variables $tn, tp, fn, fp$.

$$ 
  \begin{align}
    sensitivity = \frac{tp}{tp+fn} = 0.999 \\ 
    specificity = \frac{tn}{tn+fp} = 0.998\\ \\
     tp + fp = 15 \\ 
     fn + tn = 4985\\ 
\end{align}
$$

The result is presented in the following table:

$$
    \begin{array}{c|ll|c}
     & Sick & Healthy & \\ 
    \hline 
    Test\ Positive & tp= \frac{4995}{997} & fp = \frac{9960}{997}  & 15 \\
    Test\ Negative & fn = \frac{5}{997} & tn= \frac{4970040}{997} & 4985 \\
    \hline 
     & \ \ \ \ \frac{5000}{997} & 4994.984955 & 5000 \\
    \end{array}
$$

Thus $ P(Sick) = \frac{\frac{5000}{997}}{5000} = \frac{1}{997} = 0.1003009027\% $.

More context: I need $P(sick)$ in order to calculate $P(sick|positive\ test)$ with Bayes formula.

EDIT: Changed title, since i think that prevalence of the disease is not the same as the probability that a randomly selected patient from a group of 5000 people has the disease.

Comment: There isn't enough information.  We need to know something about the actual distribution of sick people.

Comment: There is no more information, the actual distribution of sick people is unknown and is exactly what i want to calculate with the given information.

Comment: Then you are out  of luck.  There isn't enough information to determine that.

Comment: To stress:   It is perfectly possible (and wouldn't even be all that surprising) that all the people are healthy.  Under such conditions, the expected number of "positive" scores (assuming that "positive"="tests positive for the illness") would be $.2\%$ of $5000$ or $10$...so seeing $15$ false positives wouldn't be that shocking.  It is even perfectly possible (though hardly probable) that everyone is sick.  We need  more information to say anything useful.

Comment: "then you are out of luck" - i was kind of thinking the same, when i saw this problem on an exam.

I need to correct my last comment:  I need to calculate the Probability of a person randomly selected from that 5000 group being sick.

Comment: Still no hope, sorry.  You need more information.  Perhaps whoever set the problem left something off.  Perhaps there is some assumption that they expect you to be aware of.  Ask that person.

Comment: If we know the number of of infected people from that group, we can provide the probability. The number of infected people are false negatives + true positives. This is something we can calculate from the specificity and sensitivity together with the test results (like i described in the naiv approach).

Can you spot where I'm wrong?

Comment: You have given us no way to tell a false positive from a real one, nor a false negative from a real one.  As I say, if my prior is "everyone in the pool is healthy", nothing you have said contradicts that nor even can you argue that my prior is statistically absurd.

Comment: If you want a solvable problem, find the Maximum Likelihood estimator.  That is, given that $15$ people test positive, let $N$ be the actual number of sick people and figure out which $N$ would give the highest probability of observing $15$.  That's a sensible approach, but there is nothing inevitable about it.  It's a standard modeling trick in Finance, though I wouldn't really recommend it for Medicine.  (In this case it's kind of obvious that the answer will be $5$, or maybe one off from that, but it is worth working it out carefully).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get all this in the comments so I'm posting it as an answer. I understand what lulu is saying although the $15$ testing positive does limit somewhat the possibilities of the prevalence of the disease. I have filled out the table below speculating a particular ratio of the $15$ who tested positive as to whether they are actually sick or not and in keeping with percentages of true positives and true negatives. $0.1\%$ of $5$ is $.005$ which I rounded down to $0$.

In this scenario, the prevalence of the sickness is $0.1\%$ in the population and the probability of having the disease if testing positive is: $$p = \frac{5}{15} = \frac{1}{3}$$

[image]

If the prevalence of the disease was $0\%$ then there would be an inconsistency of false positives $(15)$ being $0.2\%$ of $5000$. See second table below.

[image]